# How to implement NSManagedObject class conforming to Mappable

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, initializer

I have a class that maps directly JSON implementing the `Mappable` (ObjectMapper Framework) protocol and I'm trying to inherit from `NSManagedObject`.

```
class AbstractModel: NSManagedObject, Mappable {

@NSManaged var uuid: String?
@NSManaged var updatedAt: String?
@NSManaged var createdAt: String?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    mapping(map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    uuid        <- map["uuid"]
    updatedAt   <- map["updatedAt"]
    createdAt   <- map["createdAt"]

}
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that the compiler complains about the `mapping(map)` that uses self before the super initializer:
`AbstractModel.swift:19:9: Use of 'self' in method call 'mapping' before super.init initializes self`

Unfortunately I cannot call the super initializer (`super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?)`) before `mapping(map)` because I need `self` to get the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with ObjectMapper, but a NSManagedObject can *only* be created using the designated initializer. However you can pass `context=nil` and insert the object into a context later.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it that way. I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution is the proper way to solve the problem but I implemented my class that way and it worked:

```
class AbstractModel: NSManagedObject, Mappable {

@NSManaged var uuid: String?
@NSManaged var updatedAt: String?
@NSManaged var createdAt: String?

override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: DBUtils().getManagedObjectContext())
}

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    var ctx = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AbstractModel", inManagedObjectContext: ctx)
    super.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ctx)

    mapping(map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    uuid        <- map["uuid"]
    updatedAt   <- map["updatedAt"]
    createdAt   <- map["createdAt"]

}
}
```

Comment: Hi...what is 'DBUtils' & MR_defaultContext in your code?

Comment: Hi, DBUtils is a Util Class that returns the current ManagedContext and MR_defaultContext() is a class from MagicalRecord.

Comment: do you have any sample project for this..interested to know how you have setup your fetchrequests and alamofireObjectMapper calls..will be great if you can share a sample prroject..thnx

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry! I just have a productive project and I cannot share it with you. Let me know if I could help in any further question.

Comment: I'm interested to hear if there were any issues that were encountered using this method. It would also be nice if you could provide the source for `DBUtils().getManagedObjectContext()`.

Comment: As far as I can remember, we didn't have any issues with this method. Unfortunately, I'm not working on this project anymore and I currently don't have access to the code. I would edit my answer if I have access to it again.

Comment: is this code still working on Swift3 on iOS 10 ? cause i cant use DButils, it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'DBUtils'"